# VirtualBox Error Missing VirtualBox-5.1.18-r114002-MultiArch_amd64.msi when trying to upgrade

Tags: virtualbox

How can I find VirtualBox-5.1.18-r114002-MultiArch_amd64.msi. I am trying to upgrade my VirtuelBox but I keep gettingthe error that it cannot find VirtualBox-5.1.18-r114002-MultiArch_amd64.msi. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the older VirtualBox by downloading Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.18-114002.vbox-extpack. Then I was able to install the lastest version on my Windows 10 laptop and it worked great.
Thank you all!